# Vertex shader won't move vertex

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, particle-system

I'm trying to create a 2D particle system with particle movement in the GPU via vertex shader (OpenGL ES). My problem is that no matter what I try I can't move the vertex on the screen. They are rendered as white dots at the specified coordinates but won't move by the offset or anything I calculate in the shader. I reduced the code massively to this basic example, which didn't work either.

I assume I somewhere made a wrong assumption about the API or concepts in general, but where?

**My vertex shader (particle.vert):**

```
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec4 v_color;

uniform vec2 offset;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;

    // Offset does not have any effect
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * vec4(a_position + offset, 0.0, 1.0)
}
```

**Fragment shader (particle.frag):**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
```

**My glue code is done with [LibGdx](https://libgdx.com/) (Java):**

```
package com.foobarfoofoobar.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes.Usage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {

  private final Mesh mesh;
  private final ShaderProgram shader;
  private final OrthographicCamera camera;

  public GameScreen() {
    mesh = new Mesh(
        true,
        3,
        3,
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 2, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE),
        VertexAttribute.ColorUnpacked());
    mesh.setVertices(new float[]{
        100f, 100f, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        150f, 150f, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        200f, 100f, 1, 1, 1, 1
    });
    mesh.setIndices(new short[]{ 0, 1, 2 });

    ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
    shader = new ShaderProgram(
        Gdx.files.internal("particle.vert").readString(),
        Gdx.files.internal("particle.frag").readString());
    if (!shader.isCompiled()) {
      Gdx.app.log("Problem loading shader:", shader.getLog());
      System.exit(1);
    }

    Vector2 displayDimensions = new Vector2(
        Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
        Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Vector2 displayCenter = displayDimensions.cpy().scl(0.5f);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(
        Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
        Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.translate(displayCenter);
    camera.update();
  }

  @Override
  public void render(float delta) {
    ScreenUtils.clear(0f, 0f, 0f, 1);

    shader.bind();

    shader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", camera.combined);
    shader.setUniform2fv("u_offset", new float[]{ 200, 0 }, 0, 2);
    mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_POINTS);
  }

  @Override
  public void show() {
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose() {
  }

  @Override
  public void resize(int width, int height) {
  }

  @Override
  public void pause() {
  }

  @Override
  public void resume() {
  }

  @Override
  public void hide() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem found:

I declared the uniform `u_offset` but used it as `offset`. After renaming the uniform in the vertex shader to `offset` it works.

This was reported in the shader's log but it did not print it because it indeed did compile.